# How to select parents with specific set of children (many-to-one) django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset, one-to-many

In a many-to-one relationship in django such as the following:

```
class Parent(model.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Child(model.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Parent)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    hobby = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    age = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

If I have N different criteria of children records, for example let N=2 and criteria be:

```
Child__name='Bob'
Child__hobby='Skiing'
Child__age__gt=16

Child__name='Billy'
Child__hobby__icontains='read'
Child__age__gte='21'
```

How can I filter out Parents if they don't have at least one child meeting each of the criteria described above?

I am preferably looking to write this in a way such that I can apply one filter at a time so I can optionally check what criteria were not met by which parents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if i understand, you need to do the filter on the Children model and get the parents of the resulting queryset:

```
qs = Children.objects.filter(
    name='billy',
    age__gte=21
).values('parent')
```